# Query to extract highest value for each ID submitted

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble with a query doing other than what I intend for it to do.
employer ID's(eh_id) for each of the employee ID's (pmt_id) I have in my database.

My query as it stands is as follows:

```
 SELECT *
  FROM employer_history table1
  WHERE eh_id =
    (
      SELECT eh_id
      FROM employer_history table2
      WHERE table1.eh_id = table2.eh_id
      group by table2.eh_id
    )
  and table1.eh_pmt_id in (131,3725)
```

What I'm getting is:

eh_id     ¦     eh_pmt_id 
   123       ¦  131
   124  ¦   131 
125 ¦   3725 
126 ¦   3725

What I'm expecting is:

eh_id     ¦     eh_pmt_id

124  ¦   131 
126 ¦   3725

I would appreciate any help on this as I am getting nowhere with it myself

Cheers

Comment: I think we need to see some sample data from your tables to understand what you're trying to accomplish..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an analytical function for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY peh_pmt_id ORDER BY eh_id DESC) Corr
        FROM employer_history 
        WHERE eh_pmt_id in (131,3725)) t1
WHERE Corr = 1
```

Comment: If you were going to use an analytic function then it would be more memory efficient to use a MAX rather than a Row_Number, as for each value if peh_pmt_id the system only needs to store and compare a single maximum value of eh_id, rather than maintain a ranked list of all values.

Comment: @Lamak After reading this answer for a second time, I applied it and it worked perfectly for me for what I was trying to achieve. Thanks, I changed my accepted answer to this as it is the one that most answered my question

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT peh_pmt_id, MAX(eh_id)
FROM employer_history
WHERE eh_pmt_id in (131,3725)
GROUP BY peh_pmt_id
```